# How to return an extended promise instance from an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm just toying around with some ideas for my framework, lets say I extended the promise class like this

```
class cool_promise extends Promise {
    cool_function() {
        console.log("I am cool");
    }
}
```

and had an async function like

```
async cool_function() {
    return "functioning";
}
```

now by default cool_function just returns a regular Promise when executed synchronously but is it possible to make the async functions specific to my framework return my extended promise class instead?

Comment: why do you need that? would `Promise.prototype.cool_function = function() {console.log('I am cool')}` be enough? anyway, extending some class does not mean modifying basic class itself(so current goal is unreachable).

Comment: @skyboyer it would work but I'd rather avoid altering the prototypes of vanilla classes. I want it to make the promise class sleeker to use with my framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async` keyword will always cause a function to return a native Promise. To return a custom promise your function needs to be declared without `async` and return the Promise directly.

You could write your async functions like normal but wrap them with a function that returns a CoolPromise instead before exposing them as part of your framework's interface:

```js
class CoolPromise extends Promise {
  coolFunction ( ) {
    return 'I am cool';
  }

  static decorate ( func ) {
    return function (...args) {
      return CoolPromise.resolve( func.call( this, ...args ) );  
    };
  }
}



// Some module with an async function in it

const module = function Module ( ) {
  async function foo( ) {
    return 'bar';
  }

  // Decorate functions before exposing them from your modules
  return {
    foo: CoolPromise.decorate( foo )
  };
}( );



// Verify that module.foo( ) returns a CoolPromise

(async ( ) => {
  console.log( await module.foo( ) );
  console.log( module.foo( ).coolFunction( ) );
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to convert it manually with `cool_promise.resolve(cool_function())`. Without using a JavaScript preprocessor, async functions will always return a native `Promise`.

An alternative sometimes is to extend the native `Promise` prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype, 'cool_function', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value() {
        console.log("I am cool");
    },
});
```

Modifying globals always risks conflicting with other libraries/user code or later changes to the language, though. Sometimes it’s better to just have a standalone function. Maybe it’ll be possible to use that kind of function in a pipeline similar to the method call syntax someday – for example, there’s a proposal that would let you do this or something like it:

```
const cool_extension = (promise) => {
    console.log("I am cool");
};

cool_function() |> cool_extension
// cool_function().cool_extension(), when extending prototype
```

And in the meantime, `cool_extension(cool_function())` is not too bad and comfortably familiar.